# Using dugway in maintenance mode

Tags: bigcartel

Is there any way to use dugway while your big cartel site is in maintenance mode?

I currently get the following error when running `dugway server`:

```
/Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/dugway-0.10.5/lib/dugway/store.rb:125:in `locale': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a way to use Dugway with stores in maintenance mode, sorry about that. Dugway uses the public Big Cartel API to retrieve store information and that's unavailable during maintenance.

Since Dugway takes advantage of caching though, you could temporarily disable maintenance mode in a store, start Dugway, and then turn on maintenance mode again. This way the store information is cached and you can test your theme with store data until you the next time you restart the server.